# View custom object records on Sites

Tags: force.com-sites

I created an email template with a link where I can retreive the Id of a given custom object record.

when I clic on the link, it will redirect me to force.com site where I can view the data belonging to that record.

But that doesnt expose anything. Any idea about it? I think it's a security matter. 
P.S. my site has access without authentification

Comment: What's the OWD for the custom object?

Comment: the Read / Create  permissions

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked you what permission does the Guest user for sites have on the custom object?

Comment: Yes I did understand you, the read / create permissions

Comment: What are you seeing when the link is clicked?  A blank page?

Comment: My VF page without data:
Example:
Campaign Name : 
Adresse:
....
All those fields are blank

Answer (score 0):

You need to give app/object permissions in order to view your custom object data after login into your force.com sites. Because the Force.sites has custom profile and Guest User License which does't have any permissions for the newly created sites.

To give permissions :
Click on Sites label->public access settings->object settings->your custom object-> set permissions.